# How to communicate with Excel files via subprocess using python?

Tags: python, excel, subprocess, office365

How do I change cells in an excel file with subprocess?
So far, my code is:

```
import subprocess
ob =subprocess.Popen(['*Path to excel file*'], shell=True)
ob.communicate('H2=test')
```

But, it doesn't do anything!

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What did you expect that code to do? How do you expect to interact with the Excel file--have you learned `openpyxl`, is the file in `csv` format, or something else? Is your difficulty with the subprocess or Excel or something else? Your question as written is much too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel doesn't have a pipe communication interface, so you can't communicate with it using the subprocess module alone.

What you want to do can be achieved using the `win32com` module, because excel has a [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) interface:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Append()
range = wb.Sheets[0].Range("A1")
range.Value = 'test'
```

However that is not the best integration with excel available. I suggest looking into `openpyxl` that allows you to open excel files without needing excel itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe here you are struggling to understand what subprocess module actually does.

When you use the `shell=True` argument in it, it is the same as if you are opening your terminal (or cmd in windows) and typing that argument in.

If you are on windows, try running `subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)` and see what happens. You should see the contents of your current directory shown. If you are on mac/linux just run `subprocess.call('ls', shell=True)` and it should do the same.

So for your task currently, this is not the right tool. However, this module can be very useful for other tasks.

Personally, I like to use openpyxl combined with Pandas to read Excel sheets to a DataFrame and manipulate it inside of python. Pandas has a nice `read_excel` function, and the docs are [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).